# Помогите устранить ошибку.

Tags: c

```
#include(stdio.h)
#include(conio.h)
#include(stdlib.h)

main()
{
  clrscr();
  int i,j,k,z[100];
  for (i=0;i<100;i=i+1)
    z[i]=rand()%100;
  for (i=0;i<100;i=i+1)
    if(z[i]<50) j=j+1;
    else k=k+1;
  printf("%d\\n",j,k);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Эта программа должна число 100 разделить на два участка... т.е. на 0<50 и 50<100, с каждого участка взять по случайному числу и вывести их на экран. Но вместо этого, она выдает, какие то, несуразные числа. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка или что я сделал неправильно?

Comment: @Nikitka, Уберите знаки # в начале каждой строчки кода, затем, используя кнопку **101010**, отредактируйте код.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы при каждом новом запуске программы получались новые псевдодслучайные числа, в начале поместите строку

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Получение первого числа (0-49):

```
int r1 = rand() % 50;
```

Получение второго числа (от 50 до 100):

```
int r2 = rand() % 51 + 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

А мне показалось, что имелось в виду что-то вроде

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    // Массивы чисел
    int z[100]; // Исходный
    int l[100]; // Меньше 50
    int g[100]; // Больше 50

    // Заполняем случайными числами
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        z[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;

    int ls = 0, gs = 0;
    // Разделяем
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        if(z[i]<50)
            l[ls++] = z[i];
        else
            g[gs++] = z[i];

    // Выводим на экран
    printf("Less than 50: ");
    for(int i = 0; i<ls; i++)
        printf("%d ", l[i]);

    printf("\n\nGreater or equal than 50: ");
    for(int i = 0; i<gs; i++)
        printf("%d ", g[i]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли все версии...